# Magento authentication bound to a store view

Tags: php, authentication, magento, e-commerce

I'd like to know if it is possible to keep a user constrained to a specific store view when authenticating?

I don't want my users to login with the same account on multiple store views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think that this will be possible by default, since Magento can distinguish only the website-level and not the Store-level or the Store View-level, for Customers.

For more clarification, please go into the Magento Admin panel, and then:-

- System > Configuration
- "Customer Configuration" Group
- "Account Sharing Options" tab
- "Share Customer Accounts" field

In this field, you can only find two options:-

1. Global
2. Per Website

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to investigate further in this way